# How to soften dogs crusty eyes?

Tags: dogs, cleaning

I had a quick question I was hoping you can help me with. I have a 15yr old Jack Russell. She's having an issue that I've never personally had to deal with.

You know how some white dogs have those brown stains running from the corners of their eyes. She's never had that before, but has started recently. The vet said it may be allergies. I know they even make special cleaning clothes for this. She also has what I'm going to call "eye boogers". These aren't dead in the corner of her eye, but about and inch down. They've hardened in place. I could probably scrape them off, but I'd take hair and probably a little skin with it.

I'm looking for a good solution. I've bathed her and it too some of it off, but just a little. My thought here, and you guys can weigh in, is to put a dab of Vaseline on both crusty areas. My thought is that it's non-toxic as people put in on their bodies all the time, it doesn't have a strong scent, and that the moisture would soften the crusties, so they'd easily peel off.

Is this a good solution or is there something better. I made sure to wet them well when bathing her and it didn't make much of a difference. They were still pretty fused on. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

My older JRT has this issue. I used a boric acid eye pad recommended by my vet. I was unable to find the one I used but it was a product like this one:
[image: wipes]

I kept them in fridge and used as needed. Easier to remove discharge before it hardens.

Boric acid is a commonly used to alleviate allergens, clean and disinfect affected areas. Here is an info sheet for more detail: 
https://www.vetinfo.com/treating-dog-allergies-boric-acid.html

Answer (score 1):

Use hand warm water a towel and a bit of time. No soap or other ingredients needed.

Dab a part of the towel in the hand warm water and apply it to the hardened boogers. The trick is to keep it moist. Do this every few minutes, and you will find the gunk will soften up and you will be able to get it lose.

Vaseline might work, but I would try it with hand warm water first.

Comment: Warm water wipe is good but won’t allocate allergy symptoms.